# Prove that $f(f^{-1}(f(M))) = f(M)$, where $f:A \rightarrow B$, and $M \subseteq A$ and $N \subseteq B$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

> Prove that $f(f^{-1}(f(M))) = f(M)$, where $f:A \rightarrow B$, and $M
>  \subseteq A$  and $N \subseteq B$

Proof:

Firstly let $f(M)=Q$ and $a \in f(f^{-1}(Q))$.By the definition there is some $b \in f^{-1}(Q)$ such that $f(b)=a$.

Since $b \in f^{-1}(Q)$, by the definition, $b \in A$ such that $f(b) \in Q$

Since $f(b) \in Q$  and $f(b)=a$, we have $a \in Q$

Secondly, let $c \in f(M)$.So there is some $d \in M$ such that $f(d)=c$.

Since $f(d) \in f(M)$, by the definition $d \in f^{-1}(f(M))$.Since $d \in f^{-1}(f(M))$ and $f(d)=c$, $$f(d) \in f(f^{-1}(f(M)))$$ and hence $c \in f(f^{-1}(f(M)))$.

---

Is there any flow in the proof ? Do you have any suggestion about the writings of the proof ?I kind of using too much 'since', what can I used instead of 'since'.

Comment: What does $ M>\subseteq A $ mean? And what's $ N $?

Comment: @Xammm it is a typo, I edited. N is a subset of B.Which part of it is not clear ?

Comment: $N$ is not used in the statement

Comment: @chi Yes I know.Originally, there were some other questions based on the given sets, so N is used there.

Comment: I think your proof is reasonably clear. I would probably be more explicit using "First, we prove $\ldots \subseteq \ldots$" and "Then, we prove $\ldots \supseteq \ldots$". I have no problems with the repeated "since" -- I like step-by-step proofs which repeat the same pattern, since they are easier to check. (Just a personal opinion, obviously)

Comment: @chi Thanks your feedback.

Comment: As @Leth said, your proof is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof seems correct, but it's a bit tedious. If $f$ was bijective, the statement would be obvious and if it isn't, $f^{-1}$ is quite a complicated, non-unique object. If you think about how $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are related, you should see that there is a usable bijection hiding somewhere.

You could build an injective $g : A \to A$, which is identity on it's own image, and a bijective $h : g(A) \to f(A)$, which is basically $(f^{-1})^{-1}$, such that $f = h \circ g$. Then $f^{-1} = h^{-1}$ and $$ f \circ f^{-1} \circ f = (h \circ g) \circ h^{-1} \circ (h \circ g) = h \circ g \circ g = h \circ g = f$$